# Best approach to write an multiline equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

What is best way to let LaTeX formate a long equation such that it matches between the borderrs of a page?

As an example I have the following expression:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bar u_e(p')\delta\Gamma^\mu u_\mu(p)=&-\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\; \gamma^\mu\ln\frac{\Delta}{\Delta_\Lambda}u_\mu(p)\\
&+\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\; \frac{1}{\Delta}\left[\frac12\left(| G_L|^2+| G_R|^2+\gamma_5| G_L|^2-\gamma_5| G_R|^2 \right)\left[\left(1-2y\right)q+2pz\right]^\mu\left[(1-z-y)m_\mu\pm m_ey \right]
+\left(\Re(G_Lg_R^*)+i\gamma_5\Im(G_Lg_R^*)\right)\right((1-2y)q+2pz\left)^\mu\right]u_\mu(p)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I broke the line at some singe points with `\\` but inside a breaket this seems not to be possible. Is this correct? Or is there a way to let LaTeX do the newline automatically?

Comment: I would not do that automatically (package `breqn` btw.). You shoud use a `split` or `multiline` or `align` here. I would always choose `\bigl(\biggl(\Bigl(...` over `\left(`. If you want to stick to this, you will have to close it with `\right.` before the `\\\`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem are not the brackets but `\left` and `right` you're using, you can't break a line inside such a combination, because they have to be inside one line to determine the needed height.

My approach would be to manually set the sizes using `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl` and `\Biggl` from amsmath (and its `\bigr` collegues for the right hand delimiter). See for example this idea. I further changed your `align*` to an `equation` that's `split`, because you're splitting an equation not aligning multiple ones :)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \bar u_e(p')\delta\Gamma^\mu u_\mu(p)
            &=
            -\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\;                 \gamma^\mu\ln\frac{\Delta}{\Delta_\Lambda}u_\mu(p)\\
            &\qquad+\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\;              \frac{1}{\Delta}
            \Bigl[
            \frac{1}{2}\bigl(| G_L|^2+| G_R|^2 +\gamma_5| G_L|^2-\gamma_5| G_R|^2 \bigr)\\
            &\qquad\qquad\times
            \bigl[(1-2y)q+2pz\bigl]^\mu\bigl[(1-z-y)m_\mu\pm m_ey \bigr]
            \\
            &\qquad\qquad +\Bigl(\Re(G_Lg_R^*)+i\gamma_5\Im(G_Lg_R^*)\Bigl)\bigl((1-2y)q+2pz\bigr)^\mu
            \Bigl]u_\mu(p)
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Yielding

[image: Sketch of splitting]

Note that this is just a sketch, this sizes should be a little more fine tuned and the line breaks fitted to logical breaks in the quite loong formula; maybe you can introduce helping variables, e.g. for the first block of `\bigl(| G_L|^2+| G_R|^2 +\gamma_5| G_L|^2-\gamma_5| G_R|^2 \bigr) = G_{\text{new}}`, something like that improves readability imho more than breaking lines.

Answer (score 6):

May be this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bar u_e(p')\delta\Gamma^\mu u_\mu(p)&= -\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\; \gamma^\mu\ln\frac{\Delta}{\Delta_\Lambda}u_\mu(p)\\
&\qquad +\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\; \frac{1}{\Delta}Au_\mu(p)
\intertext{where}
A&= \biggl[\frac12(| G_L|^2+| G_R|^2+\gamma_5| G_L|^2-\gamma_5| G_R|^2 )[(1-2y)q+2pz]^\mu\\
&\qquad [(1-z-y)m_\mu\pm m_ey ]
+(\Re(G_Lg_R^*)+i\gamma_5\Im(G_Lg_R^*))((1-2y)q+2pz)^\mu\biggr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no automatic way to break as `breqn` is not stable. Also, I removed all `\left` and `\right`s as they are not needed. For the outer pair, I have used `\bigg` constructs from `amsmath` which can be broken across lines without balancing.

Comment: Should't the last line be started with some sort of multiplication marker symbol (just for good meaure)?

Answer (score 5):

The following suggestion splits the full equation across five lines, and it uses changes in size *and* style of the typographic "fences" --  round parentheses, square brackets, and curly braces -- to help guide the visual parsing of the full expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bar u_e(p')\delta\Gamma^\mu u_\mu(p)=
&-\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz \int_0^{1-z} dy\; \gamma^\mu\ln\frac{\Delta}{\Delta_\Lambda}u_\mu(p)\\
&+\frac{ie}{32\pi^2}\bar u_e(p')\int^1_0 dz\int_0^{1-z} dy\; \frac{1}{\Delta}\\
&\qquad \times
\biggl\{\frac12\bigl[| G_L|^2+| G_R|^2+\gamma_5| G_L|^2-\gamma_5| G_R|^2 \,\bigr]\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad\times \bigl[(1-2y)q+2pz\bigr]^\mu
     \bigl[(1-z-y)m_\mu\pm m_ey \bigr]\\
&\qquad\qquad+\bigl[\Re(G_Lg_R^*)+i\gamma_5\Im(G_Lg_R^*)\bigr]
\bigl[(1-2y)q+2pz\bigr]^\mu \biggr\} u_\mu(p)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```